# how to ping the server in every time limit using url

Tags: android

i have code for hitting url but it hit only once when i run the progrm i want it hit automaticly in every 5 min. for checking the status how to do it....actually i am new in android and java so pls explain with example...v.v. thanks in advance.....
public class Activity2
{
     public static String getData() {
            String data = null;
                      try {

```
                  URL url = new URL("http://qrrency.com/mobile/j2me/cab/CabRequestStatus.php?requestid=666");
                                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                    int m=0;
                    StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
                String str1 = " ";
                    while ((m=in.read())!=-1) 
                    {
                                buffer.append((char)m);
                                str1=str1+(char)m;
                                cabbookingapplication.resp =str1;
                                data=cabbookingapplication.resp;


                    }



                   in.close();



                    } catch (MalformedURLException e)
                    {
                    } catch (IOException e) 
                    {

                }
                return data;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the timer after every 5 min it will hit the Url which u want & will do what u want.

Comment: thanks sir...but sir how to implement it??? actually i am new in java and android pls pls.....write it in my code..pls

Comment: @Override
 public void onResume() 
 {
   super.onResume();
     autoUpdate = new Timer();
     autoUpdate.schedule(new TimerTask() 
     {
     @Override
      public void run() 
      {
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
       {
        public void run() 
        {
         dis(++count);// write the method in which u r hitting url after 5 min
        }
       }); 
      }
     },0,30000); // updates each 60 secs
   } // we can use at max 100000000 digit with timer.
     
   @Override
      public void onPause() 
   {  
     autoUpdate.cancel();
     super.onPause();
      }